# Where is system.log located? (In the filesystem, outside of Console.app)

Tags: macos, filesystem, logs, console

Where is the system.log file actually located? I know of course that I can view its contents in Console.app, but I just want to know where this text file is actually located. Or is it an almagamation of multiple files merged together or something, so that's why there's no actual location for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click it in Console.app - Reveal in Finder :)

For completeness, it's located in `/private/var/log`.